# input mask for email with react

Tags: reactjs

I search the internet to find how the input mask for email with react like [this one](https://surveyjs.io/form-library/examples/control-data-entry-formats-with-input-masks/reactjs) is made without libraries but I found nothing.
Can someone please help with this.
Thank you.

Comment: If you don't want to use any libraries then you will need to write the functions your self. set the value to `_@_._` from the start then create a onChange function that will manipulate this field in the way you want then set the value of the input field to that. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know, that's the idea but I'm struggling with how to write the function that will manipulate the field